# Object passed to jade ends up as string

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I want to pass an object from node to jade, and use it there in my js.
but it ends up as `[object Object]` string, i don't know why

serverside

```
var currentProblem = problemMaker.makeProblem(level);
console.dir(currentProblem); // [ { value: 2, operation: '+' }, {value: 1, operation: '-' } ]

res.render('training', {
    // ...
    Oid             : problemOid,
    problemObject   : JSON.stringify(currentProblem)
});
```

jade

```
script(type='text/javascript').
    var problemOid = "!{Oid}"  // this WORKS
script(type='text/javascript').
    var problemObj = "!{JSON.parse(problemObject)}"  // this does NOT
```

(note that webstorm marks "problemObject" as unresolved variable, while Oid seems to be no problem)

browser js

```
console.log(typeof problemObj);  // string
console.dir(problemObj);         // [object Object],[object Object]
```

i tried it with and without stringify/parse, no difference.
what am i doing wrong?

thanks

## Solution

I got it working by remnoving the quotes and removing any JSON.xxxx

working code:

```
script(type='text/javascript') var problemObj = !{problemObject};
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove commas and use `JSON.stringify` insteadof `JSON.parse`

```
script var problemObj = !{JSON.stringify(problemObject)};
```

Main idea here

```
var str = JSON.stringify({a: 1000}); // returns string "{"a":1000}"
console.log(str); // print {"a":1000}
```

So, in your html you would see

```
script var str = !{JSON.stringify({a: 1000})}; 

->

<script>
    var str = {"a":1000};
</script>
```

Comment: almost there, it shows the content now, but it's still typeof string

Comment: did you remove commas around?

Comment: yes (i think you mean the quotes?):
  script(type='text/javascript').
    var problemObj = !{JSON.stringify(problemObject)}

Comment: ok i got it right now. it works WITHOUT JSON.stringify or parse (and without quotes)